# $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2/(n^2 + k^2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How can I compute the following sum exactly: $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2/(n^2 + k^2)?$$ (I can approximate it by a Riemann integral, but that's not my goal).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk%5E2%2F(k%5E2%2Bn%5E2),%7Bk%3D1,n%7D%5D

Comment: Pretty sure it has no simple closed form in terms of elementary functions. Yes we can write it in terms of generalized harmonic number like functions however they are pretty much defined as being such a sum...

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{2} \left(i H_{(1-i) n}-i H_{(1+i) n}+\frac{1}{n}-\pi  \coth (\pi  n)+2\right)$, where $H_n$ is the harmonic number $H(n)$
The limit as $n\to \infty$ is $1-\frac{\pi }{4}$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k^{2} \over n^{2} + k^{2}} & =
{1 \over n}\,\Re\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over k + \ic n} =
1 + {1 \over n}\,\Re\pars{-\ic n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 + \ic n}}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 + \ic n} -
{1 \over k + n + 1 + \ic n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{1 + \Im\pars{H_{n + \ic n} - H_{\ic n}}}\qquad\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\end{align}

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{J}$?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb $\Im$ stands for $\texttt{Imaginary Part}$. Similarly, $\Re$ stands for $\texttt{Real Part}$. The $\LaTeX$-code is $\texttt{\Im}$ and $\texttt{\Re}$, respectively. Thanks.